# Rx, Tx/UART not being detected by Pi? What is wrong?

Tags: pi-3, arduino, uart, communication

I'm working on Serial communication between the Raspberry Pi and the Arduino, with the Raspberry Pi serving as master. I connected, using a logic level shifter, Arduino's Rx (Software Serial was used for Arduino) to Raspberry Pi's Tx, and the Pi's Rx to the Arduino's Tx.

After this, I ran a code from the Arduino which would just send a number to the Pi, I ran the Python code below to basically read data received from the Arduino.

```
import serial
import time
from time import sleep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 38400, timeout = 100)
    ser.flush
    
    while True:
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
            print(line, flush = True)
            if float(line) == 600:
                ser.write(b"200\n")
```

However, when I ran it, I just got the error that the ACM0 was not found in the directory. What was I supposed to do?

Comment: Did you connect Ground and presumable 5V and 3.3V to the required sides?

Comment: Yeah I did, and I can confirm that the shifter works too as I had used it for I2C prior.

Comment: I soldered a new one and tested it again, yet again nothing, I did do a /dev/tty* to see if a new device would appear but nothing came.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using /dev/serial0 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 (PiZeroW, Pi4 or later models)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3-pizerow-pi4-or-later-models)

Comment: Are you sending the number from the arduino as text?

Answer (score 1):

Your UART is more likely on /dev/ttys0.  You can verify this by doing `ls /dev/tty*`

You also need to make sure (in raspi-config) that you have disabled the serial terminal, but make sure to leave the hardware enabled.